# setting cron job in godaddy.com cpanel

Tags: cron, cpanel

I need to setup cron job command,   my script provider gave me this full code and tell me to modify as per cpanel.  i am confused where to start to get the details for the command.   please help.

Provided command:-
/usr/local/bin/php "/home/olkumfvp/public_html/wp-content/uploads/scripts/script
v.1.14/cron.php" >> "/home/olkumfvp/public_html/wp-content/uploads/scripts/script
v.1.14/cronlog.txt" 2>&1

instructions given:-

/usr/local/bin/php is the path to PHP.
"/home/olkumfvp/public_html/script/cron.php" is the path to the cron.php file on server.
"/home/olkumfvp/public_html/script/cronlog.txt" indicates where to save logs for cron.
System will create this file if it does not exist
2>&1 Keep this as is.

I am requesting you that,  please tell me where can i see my cpanel path, example:- i saw 2 paths in php folder in my cpanel :-

Paths and Directories   include_path    Windows: "\path1;\path2" c:\php\includes"                              .:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php

please some one modify the code

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you please do not change anything in your code. Just login your cPanel and try to setup cronjob with the following command.

```
php -q "/home/olkumfvp/public_html/wp-content/uploads/scripts/script v.1.14/cron.php" >> "/home/olkumfvp/public_html/wp-content/uploads/scripts/script v.1.14/cronlog.txt" 2>&1
```

Please confirm your cPanel user name and update that command instead of "olkumfvp " and let us know if you are getting any issues.

Comment: after setting thecron job, i got this mail...       /usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell: /home/olkumfvp/public_html/wp-content/uploads/scripts/script v.1.14/cronlog.txt: No such file or directory

Comment: sorry i changed my cpanel user name  but still same error is comming.. please help.     after setting the cron job, i got this mail...       /usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell: /home/saiprasanth9012/public_html/wp-content/uploads/scripts/script v.1.14/cronlog.txt: No such file or directory

Comment: love u dude, u give a hint to me. i edited the line completely with my path.   thank u very much.

Comment: check your /home/saiprasanth9012/public_html/wp-content/uploads/scripts/script v.1.14/cronlog.txt file and if it's not created, create it and test this again.